# same function for two buttons in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, buttonclick

I have two buttons: `btnAdd` and `btnUpdate`. I have written a jquery function for button `btnUpdate` to validate some fields in the web page like:

```
$(function() {

  $('#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>').click(function() {
    code here
    });
});
```

I want to do the same thing when `btnAdd` is clicked. So I have to write the same function again for btnAdd. Is there other way to avoid this?

(If I write one javascript function and call the same function in the button click event of both buttons, it's fine. But is there any way using jQuery?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just make a selection of two buttons, separated by a comma:  `("#add, #update").click...`
Looks like this in your code:

```
$(function() { 

  $('#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>, #<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').click(function() { 
    code here 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: you should mention that Refactoring is a huge step in developing.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways.

(1) Select both elements at once and apply the event handler to them:

```
$(function() {
    $('#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>, #<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        code here
    });
});
```

(2) Give the function a name, rather than leaving anonymous:

```
function clickHandler() {
  // code here
}

$('#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>, #<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').click(clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 7):

We call this **[Refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)** and it's something that will help you all the way, read more about, **invest in yourself** and buy the fantastic one and only [Refactoring book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)

in your case, you should do this:

```
$(function() {

  $('#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        validate($this);
    });
  $('#<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        validate($this);
    });    

});

function validate(myButton)
{
    // code here
}
```

As you **should always do**.

but as jQuery you can have selectors with multiple inputs, so all you need to do is:

```
$('#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>, #<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').click(function() { 
    validate($this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a JavaScript framework, not another language, so you can write one JavaScript function here too.

```
function validateFields(e) {
    code here;
}

$(function() {
  $('#<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>').click(validateFields);
  $('#<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').click(validateFields);
});
```