# Access click event of two buttons using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 html button named Button1 and Button2.

The two button performs same operation using jquery.

now i wrote the same jquery in click event of both buttons.thats shown below

```
 $('#Button1').click(function () {
 xyz //some jquery
  })



 $('#Button2').click(function () {
 xyz //some jquery
  })
```

The both jquery are same. Can i catch the click event of both 
button in single function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810731/same-function-for-two-buttons-in-jquery

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('#Button1, #Button2').click(function() {
    // You can use `this` to refer to the source element, for instance:
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

Comment: @fedric. Just want to clarify some dobt.If i did so, is there any way to understand which button causes the event????

Comment: @Null Pointer, yes, you can use `this` in the event handler to refer to the source element.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a class on the buttons:

```
$('.className').click(function() {
    var item = $(this); // item that triggered the event

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a function and use it as a parameter. For example:

```
function handleClick() {
    // Do something..
}

$('#Button1').click(handleClick);
$('#Button2').click(handleClick);
```

Hope this helped.